# CMake not respecting command line options

Tags: cmake

Ubuntu 14_04, gcc 4.8.4, cmake 2.8.12.2

I wish to add additional options to [UnitTest++](https://github.com/unittest-cpp/unittest-cpp). I added code coverage via UTPP_CODE_COVERAGE but leave it off for regular builds. This seemed to fail - nothing is in the Makefile that looks to be specified via the `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` option.

So I looked at whether the `UTPP_AMPLIFY_WARNINGS` command works

Whether I compile with it on or off, no difference is made to the Makefile.

At the terminal I compile with

> `$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DUTPP_AMPLIFY_WARNINGS=ON ../`

But when I analyse the generated Makefile `-Wall` is nowhere to be found in the output.  It's not even in the CMakeCache.txt

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the output of 'make VERBOSE=1' show -Wall? The CMakeLists.txt for this project doesn't write the updated CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS back to the cache, so -Wall won't appear in CMakeCache.txt. Grep your build directory recursively for -Wall to see where it's specified.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm what you have observed. There seems that the required warning level is already default in the `CMakeLists.txt` file and also the command `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -Werror")` setting the -Wall flag is reached and executed (have tested this using message(). If there is no other answer here, at least you know you are not alone wondering how it comes.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.1)
project(UnitTest++)

option(UTPP_USE_PLUS_SIGN
    "Set this to OFF if you wish to use '-cpp' instead of '++' in lib/include paths"
    ON)
option(UTPP_INCLUDE_TESTS_IN_BUILD
    "Set this to OFF if you do not wish to automatically build or run unit tests as part of the default cmake --build"
    ON)
option(UTPP_AMPLIFY_WARNINGS
    "Set this to OFF if you wish to use CMake default warning levels; should generally only use to work around support issues for your specific compiler"
    ON)

...

# up warning level for project
if (${UTPP_AMPLIFY_WARNINGS})
    # instead of getting compiler specific, we're going to try making an assumption that an existing /W# means
    # we are dealing with an MSVC or MSVC-like compiler (e.g. Intel on Windows)
    if(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS MATCHES "/W[0-4]")
        # message(STATUS "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS MATCHES")
        string(REGEX REPLACE "/W[0-4]" "/W4" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /WX")
    else()
        # message(STATUS "set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS")
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -Werror")
    endif()
endif()
```

Comment: Even if I try to turn it off nothing appears in the makefile. I was looking to add my own option to the makefile but would be by default off.  I wasn't getting the expected output so I started looking at the ones that come with it.